# Eclipse Raspberry Pi 3 remote debugging ImportError: No module named 'bluetooth'

Tags: python, eclipse, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, remote-debugging

I am trying to do a Bluetooth scan on my  Raspberry pi 3. I am using eclipse remote debugging for coding. Python version is 3.4

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\SachithW\Downloads\eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.1.2.201606231256\pysrc')

import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('192.168.1.11') # replace IP with address 
                            # of Eclipse host machine
import bluetooth
```

I have installed "Python bluez" and "Bluetooth" in the raspberry pi device.

```
 sudo apt-get install bluetooth
 sudo apt-get install bluez
 sudo apt-get install python-bluez
 pip install pybluez
```

But when I run the code it gives me this error massage.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\eclipse\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\192.168.1.4\home\pi\pi_projects\BT_multiple.py", line 6, in 
    import bluetooth
ImportError: No module named 'bluetooth'

What is the cause for this error? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-bluez
```

I have also seen this in tutorials:

```
pip install pybluez
```

Comment: It was not in your list. Added one more thing to try.